# Consulta linq relacion muchos a muchos 3 tablas EF Core

Tags: sql, linq

Tengo el siguiente escenario en .net core 3.1 usando EF 3.2.1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento hacer una consulta que me devuelva el campo Name de la tabla Captions junto al campo sentence de la tabla Translates y filtrando por el campo Language de la tabla Translates, en SQL seria el siguiente codigo que funciona perfecto:

```
  SELECT Captions.Name AS Name,
  Translates.Sentence AS Sentence
  FROM Captions
  INNER JOIN CaptionTranslates ON (Captions.CaptionId = CaptionTranslates.CaptionId)
  INNER JOIN Translates ON (Translates.TranslateId = CaptionTranslates.TranslateId)
  WHERE Translates.Language = "ES"
```

Intento pasarlo a linq pero no soy capaz, no me duvuelve el resultado que necesito. He mirado otros hilos pero no acabo de entender como realizar la consulta en linq de las tres tablas. No acabo de entender como seleccionar solo los campos que necesito.

Muchas gracias por la ayuda, un saludo

Answer (score -1):

Bueno dejo mi propia respuesta por si le puede servir a alguien:

```
public IEnumerable<TextsDTO> GetTextsByLanguage(string lang)
        {
            var texts = (from c in _context.Captions
                         join ct in _context.CaptionTranslates on c.CaptionId equals ct.CaptionId
                         join t in _context.Translates on ct.TranslateId equals t.TranslateId
                         where t.Language == lang
                         select new TextsDTO { 
                         
                             Caption = c.Name,
                             Sentence = t.Sentence,
                             Language = t.Language
                         
                         }).ToList();

            return texts;
        }
```

Un saludo.